# execute 2 commands in File shortcut

Tags: windows, cmd, shortcut

I am using Windows 7 professional.

I have auto generated file shortcut for the program.

I need to delete one folder before starting the program every time.

Can I automatize it without creating .bat file? e.g. using this command `del \directory\path\* /g "C:\Program Files (x86)\program.exe"` in the shortcut properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do this:

```
C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /C "del \directory\path\* /Q & "C:\Program Files (x86)\program.exe"
```

The `&` sign tells the shell to run several commands in sequence.